# Making buttons link to different ViewControllers in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have made a Tabbed Applications with 4 tabs. With the first tab Decors, I have used the [Scrolling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html) example from apple website. I have edited it so it uses 24 images that scroll vertically across the page.

How do I link each one of my images that I have looped to link to a new ViewController

I have uploaded my project to http://blakeloizides.co.za/xcode/ for you to see and maybe play around with.

[image]

Comment: do you want to link the button to viewController or image to viewController??????

Comment: I want to be able to click on say e.g Windsor Grey color swatch image above and be linked to a new page with a image with a image and some text underneath it. I want to do this with all images in my scrollview. Each image goes to a new page that has some information on it.

Comment: @venkat Well I have 24images that scroll. I want each image to go to thier own modal or viewcontroller. E.G Windsor Grey pops up a modal displaying some text, Or when you click on Balsa image it pops up a modal saying some text for balsa.

Comment: You can use navigation to another view or might as well use a modalViewController. But i am not able to get why have you tagged it in java also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a tag to each of your buttons. If you are using a for loop, the tag can be index counter (i) + 1. Each button can have the same selector

```
for (int i =0; i<24; i++) 
{
    //create your button here
    [button setTag:(i+1)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    int tag = theButton.tag;
    //based on tag, do an action here - move to a different viewcontroller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the each image in `UIImageView` with each unique `tag` property and and put the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it.Once Gesture will recognize the tap, based on the `tag` property load the new `Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

In next View set ImageView and label, and set all imageName as 1.png, 2.png.... and apply for loop

```
for (int i =0; i<24; i++) 
        {
            NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i];
            UIImageView *imageView= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        }
```